# Add dynamic json to static json

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, serialization

I'm having difficulty creating some code that dynamically creates graphs:

The following code snippet helps create the graph:

```
                xGrid: false,
                legend: true,
                title: 'Meetings and Hours Used',
                points: [
                    [7, 26, 33, 74, 12, 49, 33, 33, 74, 12, 49, 33],
                    [32, 46, 75, 38, 62, 20, 52, 75, 38, 62, 20, 52]
                ],
```

And I've replaced the points section with this:

```
points: <%= getJson() %>
```

And my code behind has function:

```
    public string getJson()
    {
        var publicationTable = new List<object>{
        new { points = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]," }


    };
        return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(publicationTable);
    }
```

The javascript doesn't seem to be parsing - can anyone please help me :)

Comment: Is this MVC Project?

Comment: isn't there an extra comma in points = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]," ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
public string getJson() {
    var publicationTable = new[] {
        new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
        new[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }
    };
    return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(publicationTable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<List<int>> lstMainArr = new List<List<int>>();
        lstMainArr.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }.ToList<int>());
        lstMainArr.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }.ToList<int>());

        Console.Write((new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(lstMainArr));
```

Answer (score 1):

> points: <%= getJson() %>

This outputs whatever the return result type is, so for example:

```
points: 8      // getJson() returns int
points: test   // getJson() returns a string
```

if you had done:

```
points = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],";
return points:
```

the result would be:

```
points = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
```

However you have:

```
var publicationTable = new List<object> {
  new { points = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]," }
};

return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(publicationTable);
```

So to determine the output, step through each outer to inner method/object.

Step 1: Serialization - Creates an empty string.

```
""
```

Step 2: Serialize `List<Object>` (basically a JavaScript array)

```
"[]"
```

Step 3: Serialize first anonymous Object:

```
"[{}]"
```

Step 4: Serialize first property :

```
"[{"points" : "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],", }]"
```

No more properties, no more objects, serialization finished.  [This is not the JSON you were looking for](https://youtu.be/532j-186xEQ?t=31s).